# Positioning Widgets inside a GUI Application (PySide)

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, position, pyside

How can i make a GUI App like this without using QT Designer:

[Image http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/856/zz53.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/856/zz53.png)

Comment: +1 for the awesome red text, -2 for showing absolutely no indication of doing any work to answer the question. Net change: -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question should really be: by [reading the finely-crafted manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html).

One of the best things about Qt is its superb documentation. It's so good, that you don't even need to know C++ to be able to use it. You're really missing out on an important part of learning PyQt/PySide if you don't famialize yourself with everything it has to offer.

But what the heck, here's a crude mock-up of what you asked for (the rest I'll leave to you as an exercise):

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Label A', self), 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Label B', self), 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Label C', self), 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Label D', self), 1, 1)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(QtGui.QRadioButton('Radio A', self))
        vbox.addWidget(QtGui.QRadioButton('Radio B', self))
        vbox.addWidget(QtGui.QRadioButton('Radio C', self))
        vbox.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self))
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(widget)
        layout.addLayout(grid, 0, 0)
        layout.addLayout(vbox, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(
            QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self), 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 100, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks again @ekhumoro, i just tried what you wrote above here, and it works perfectly, this is the real code, omitting some other implements: http://codepad.org/CoppVOAE if you want to give a look..
Anyway you can also try it out, cus i'd like to display the radiobuttons in the top of the VBoxLayout, and not right in the middle of it. When i got some free time, i'll try to give a look to the guide you posted before, thanks again for answering me!

Comment: I wish documentation was good for less basic stuff. Working in c++ is big plus if you really want to take full advantage of documentation for qt that is online. I guarantee at some point you will end up at the C++ documentation, and find it has no equivalent in PySide/PyQt.